# sumar filas de una pivot table pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Me he generado una pivot_table para poder ver algunas filas en columnas y quisiera poder sumar el dato de algunas de esas columnas para obtener un total. Al ser una pivot_table, no me reconoce el nombre de las columnas:

```
datos = {'num': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     'color': ['azul', 'azul', 'rojo', 'verde','amarillo','amarillo'],
                      'deporte': ['fútbol', 'béisbol', 'natación','natación','béisbol','fútbol'],
                      'calif': [100, 90, 70, 80,80,100],
                      'nombres': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
                      'zona':['Norte', 'Norte', 'Norte', 'Sur', 'Sur', 'Este'],
                      'puntos':[5,10,20,15,5,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df



tabla = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['zona','deporte'], columns=['nombres'], values=['puntos'],aggfunc='sum')
tabla
```

Mi intención es obtener una nueva columna con la suma de las columnas creadas con la `pivot_table:['A'+'B']` y otra columna con la suma de `['A'+'C']`.

He intentado hacer:

```
tabla["suma total AB"] = sum(tabla['A','B'])
```

Pero no lo consigo ya que los nombres de A, B y C no los considera encabezados de columnas.
(soy novato, soy consciente). Desde ya, muchas gracias y perdón si falta alguna información

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que parece no identificar las columnas es porque al crear tu `pivot_table` se crean 2 niveles de columnas y si revisas

```
print(tabla.columns)
```

Vas a ver que obtienes tuplas con los elementos del primer nivel y el segundo nivel, de la siguiente forma:

```
MultiIndex([('puntos', 'A'),
            ('puntos', 'B'),
            ('puntos', 'C')],
           names=[None, 'nombres'])
```

Podrías eliminar el nivel de `puntos` si al final de tu `pivot_table` agregas `['puntos']`.

La función que intentas agregar no funciona porque el argumento `aggfunc` recibe un diccionario que se compone por el nombre de la columna y la operación a realizar.

Yo te recomendaría rellenar los `NaN` con ceros para que los datos se vieran mejor

Juntando estos tres comentarios la línea quedaría así:

```
tabla = df.pivot_table(index=['zona','deporte'], columns=['nombres'], values=['puntos'], aggfunc={'puntos':'sum'})['puntos'].fillna(0)
```

Al imprimir `tabla` obtenemos:

```
        nombres A   B       C
zona    deporte         
Este    fútbol  0.0 0.0     3.0
Norte   béisbol 0.0 10.0    0.0
fútbol          5.0 0.0     0.0
natación        0.0 20.0    0.0
Sur béisbol     5.0 0.0     0.0
natación        0.0 0.0     15.0
```

Por último, para agregar las columnas con las sumas de `'A' + 'B'` y de `'A' + 'C'` puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) con el argumento `axis = 1` que hace que las sumas sean por fila

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {'num': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 'color': ['azul', 'azul', 'rojo', 'verde','amarillo','amarillo'],
                  'deporte': ['fútbol', 'béisbol', 'natación','natación','béisbol','fútbol'],
                  'calif': [100, 90, 70, 80,80,100],
                  'nombres': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
                  'zona':['Norte', 'Norte', 'Norte', 'Sur', 'Sur', 'Este'],
                  'puntos':[5,10,20,15,5,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

tabla = df.pivot_table(index=['zona','deporte'], columns=['nombres'], values=['puntos'], aggfunc={'puntos':'sum'})['puntos'].fillna(0)

tabla['AB'] = tabla.loc[:,['A', 'B']].sum(axis = 1)
tabla['AC'] = tabla.loc[:,['A', 'C']].sum(axis = 1)
print(tabla)
```

Que imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
nombres           A     B     C    AB    AC
zona  deporte                              
Este  fútbol    0.0   0.0   3.0   0.0   3.0
Norte béisbol   0.0  10.0   0.0  10.0   0.0
      fútbol    5.0   0.0   0.0   5.0   5.0
      natación  0.0  20.0   0.0  20.0   0.0
Sur   béisbol   5.0   0.0   0.0   5.0   5.0
      natación  0.0   0.0  15.0   0.0  15.0
```

**Nota adicional:** Cuando redactes preguntas siempre procura hacerlo con `python` estandar, en tu pregunta vemos por ejemplo la línea `df` o `tabla` que parece indicar que utilizas `JupyterLab` o algo similar (Trabajo con celdas) pero no todas las personas trabajan de esa forma por lo que es recomendable incluir los `print` para que se entienda mejor lo que estás haciendo.